PowerBi - Datetime value loses 1 second when changing the field type from DateTime to Text
I have a DateTime value called "Hour". It represents each hour (rounded) of the day.
Due to other transformations I want to apply, I need to change the field's type to Text.
However, when I add a step to change the type to Text, the datetime value loses 1 second. This is wreaking havoc with my visualizations.

23:00:00 becomes 22:59:59
22:00:00 becomes 21:59:59
etc.

Why does this happen? How can I prevent this? I've tried recreating all the steps from afresh but get the same result.
One odd thing I've noticed is that this issue tends to come and go with time, without me making any changes to the dashboard. One day it's there, and another day all the time fields end with 00. The underlying data source for the dates is a static Excel document and the data in the document seems fine and unrelated to the problem.
**Before: **

**After: **


Do you you have code and sample data to replicate the issue?

Do you get the same issue when using  #"DateTimeToText" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Your Previous Step", {"Hour", each DateTime.ToText(_, [Format="yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:00"]), type text}) ?

Hi @SamNseir, your code results in 23:00:00 becoming 22:59:00

@davidebacci what would you like me to share additionally? The sample data and transformation step's code are in the screenshots.

And what do you get with this: = Table.TransformColumns(#"Changed Type", {"Hour", each DateTime.ToText(_ + #duration(0, 0, 0, 10), [Format="yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:00"]), type text})? If you could share an example value from Excel formatted as a number (not date).

You need to share sample data as copiable text. No one want to type that out. You also haven't shared any code. Copy your code from the advanced editor so we can see everything you are doing.
